# A fair die is thrown repeatedly until we obtain the same number twice in a row.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

> A fair die is thrown repeatedly until we obtain the same number twice in a row. Compute the expected number of throws.

For this, I found $6$ finding the transition matrix and using first step analysis.

Is there any other way to find expected number without using markov chain?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider a negative binomial with probability of success $p=5/6$, $r=1$ (the one failure, is when the dice match), and add $1$ to the expectation for the first roll.

Answer (score 4):

Would you say that a recursive argument is the same argument as the one using markov chains? After the first toss, say the expectation is $E$.  On the next toss you either get a double (probability $\frac 16$) or you wind up back at square one (probability $\frac 56$).  Hence $$E=\frac 16 \times 1+\frac 56 \times (E+1)\implies E=6$$

Adding back that first toss, we see that the answer is $\fbox 7$.

Comment: But, I do not see why the answer I found using markov chain is different from yours.. I got 6.

Comment: I expect you neglected to add back that first toss.

Comment: Is 7 the exact answer? I mean on the exam, I got it right.. even though I put 6 , weird..

Comment: I don't see any argument for neglecting that first toss.  Of course, the exam question might have directed you to imagine that you had been throwing the die for a while (so you are already in the "Active State").

Comment: Think of it in States.  There are three states here:  Start, Active, End.  It takes $1$ toss to get from Start to Active.  Active goes to End with probability $\frac 16$ and otherwise stays in Active, hence you expect it to take $6$ trials to go from Active to End.  That's $7$ altogether.

Comment: Can we also think of 7 states? 6 states of which are numbers on die and one of which is absorbing state?

Comment: Sure, it's just unnecessary.  The faces are all equivalent...,makes no difference which one is up.  Have you persuaded yourself that $7$ is the correct answer?  You can do it by brute force...the expected number is just $\frac 16\times \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\;n\,\left(\frac 56 \right)^{n-2}$.